# FormCollection not populating

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC project which I want to pass a FormCollection, populated with form data, and post it to my action method in my controller.  Here's an example of the view:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClientLastName" name="txtClientLastName" runat="server" class="focus"/>
```

(Yes, I know!  ASP controls in an MVC view isn't good but that's what I have.  There's back end code in the view between  tags as well which is why I haven't replaced them)

I've used a helper to link to my action:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Save","ClientInformationEdit",new {id=Model.PersonId})%
```

which calls my action:

```
 public ActionResult ClientInformationEdit(int id, FormCollection form)
   {
        //rptLOA_GridCommands(form, id);

       CIHelper ch = new CIHelper();


       ch.person.LastName = form["txtClientLastName"]; 
       db.SaveChanges();

        return View(ch);
    }
```

My ìd`passes the correct value but FormCollection form is null so form["txtClientLastName"] is null and I don`t know why.

Comment: Have you put your submit button within a form html element?

Comment: if possible post your view.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Add post attribute like below:

```
     [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ClientInformationEdit(int id, FormCollection form)
   {
        //rptLOA_GridCommands(form, id);

       CIHelper ch = new CIHelper();


       ch.person.LastName = form["txtClientLastName"]; 
       db.SaveChanges();

        return View(ch);
    }
```

If you want to post form on click of hyperlink then add following code:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Save","ClientInformationEdit",new {id=Model.PersonId,onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();"})%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I`ve had problems with adding HttpPost and getting a 404 Error in the past.  There`s already a form tag in the view

Comment: post your view so that it is easy to check the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ClientInformationEdit", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.PersonId"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientLastName" name="txtClientLastName" runat="server" class="focus"/>    
    <input type ="submit"/>
}
```

in your view